# R script to split rows consisting of strings and numbers based on value in particular column

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting

Essentially I am trying to take a data frame with strings and numbers and split it into separate new data frames based on the value in a specific column. I found functions that do this with matrices, but have not been successful in getting this to work.

I would like to take a data frame looking something like this example below (but with many more rows and columns) and sort them all based on their value under "TaxonID", which is a number 1-6.

```
Species TaxonId sulfur nitrogen ammonia nitrite
Species1    1   718 75  90  63
Species2    1   718 75  90  63
Species3    6   46  22  2   1
Species4    6   67  26  0   0
Species5    5   9   5   0   0
```

To create:

df1:

```
Species TaxonId sulfur nitrogen ammonia nitrite
Species1    1   718 75  90  63
Species2    1   718 75  90  63
```

df5:

```
Species TaxonId sulfur nitrogen ammonia nitrite
Species5    5   9   5   0   0
```

df6:

```
Species TaxonId sulfur nitrogen ammonia nitrite
Species3    6   46  22  2   1
Species4    6   67  26  0   0
```

And advice would be much appreciated, thank you for taking time to help a novice :)

Comment: `split(x, x$TaxonId)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` to do this.

Say your dataframe is called `dat`, you can do

```
split_dat <- split(dat, dat$TaxonID)
```

You can then retrieve each dataframe from the list `split_dat`

```
df1 <- split_dat["1"]
df6 <- split_dat["6"]
```

Haven't tested this - you may have to convert `TaxonID` to a character first with `as.character`